# how to write checkbox value to database as 1/0 instead of on/0 with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, types, checkbox

trying to save the checkbox 'checked status in my database. I am using codeigniter for this. I add the cehckbox form value to the array as follows:
`'treated' =>  $this->input->post('treated'.$i),`

I then write to database passing my array which contains the above input.

this is written to the database as 'on' and works with `char/varchar`. if however I change this to `bit` or `tinyint(1)` it fails with mssql error `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'on' to data type tinyint.`

How can I pass the checked checkbox value as `1` instead of `on`?

Thanks in advance.

**update**

```
 $i=1;
    while($i<=$this->input->post('orderlines'))
  {
$treatedVal=$this->input->post('treated'.$i)?1:0;

      //set the data for line insert start
        $data = array(
      'treated' => $treatedVal,    
        );

        $this->sales_model->order_lines_insert($data);  
  $i++;
  }
```

Comment: It's in your HTML reference of choice. Please *use* it. E.g. replace the value `on` with `1`. Done.

Comment: simple you can do it using `isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Thanks Dipesh, not working, still passing 'on' to the database?

Comment: please put your html for checkbox here?

Comment: @Smudger I'm wondering why the problem has not be solved. as a side-point, to convert a `string` to `integer` (`0` or `1`) I suggest something like `inval(!!$string);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change it in the HTML itself.

```
<html>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" />  <!--give it a value attribute the default is "on"-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do this before creating data array

```
 $treatedVal=$this->input->post('treated'.$i)?1:0;
 // then add this variable value to your array
 'treated' => $treatedVal,
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, this does not work `on` still being passed to the database? error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'on' to data type tinyint.` my syntax is updated in the question...

Comment: @Smudger what comes in $treatedVal and print the last_query()

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
var myVal = ( $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;

alert('myVal is: ' +myVal); //alerts 1 if checked, 0 if not checked
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjyntj1b/)</kbd>